# Proof writing: $\varepsilon$-$\delta$ proof of a limit non-existence

Tags: limits, epsilon-delta

Let
$$
f(x) =
\left\{
 \begin{array}{ll}
  x+1  & \mbox{if } x > 1 \\
  x & \mbox{if } x < 1
 \end{array}
\right.
$$
Show that $$\lim_{x \to 1} f(x) \neq \frac{3}{2}$$

**My proof**

I need to prove that there exists no possible $\delta>0$ and $\varepsilon>0$ combination that satisfies
$$
\left|f(x)-\frac{3}{2}\right|<\varepsilon \text{ whenever } |x-1|<\delta
$$

For $1<x<1+\delta$, $f(x)=1+x$
$$
\left|f(x)-\frac{3}{2}\right|=\left|x+1-\frac{3}{2}\right|=\left|x-\frac{1}{2}\right|
$$
Let $x=1+\delta_m$ such that $0<\delta_m<\delta$
$$
\left|f(x)-\frac{3}{2}\right|=\left|x-\frac{1}{2}\right|=\left|1+\delta_m-\frac{1}{2}\right|=\delta_m+\frac{1}{2} \\
\implies \left|f(x)-\frac{3}{2}\right|>\frac{1}{2}
$$

For $1-\delta<x<1$, $f(x)=x$
$$
\left|f(x)-\frac{3}{2}\right|=\left|x-\frac{3}{2}\right|
$$
Let $x=1-\delta_m$ such that $0<\delta_m<\delta$
$$
\left|f(x)-\frac{3}{2}\right|=\left|x-\frac{3}{2}\right|=\left|1-\delta_m-\frac{3}{2}\right|=\left|-\delta_m-\frac{1}{2}\right|=\delta_m+\frac{1}{2} \\
\implies \left|f(x)-\frac{3}{2}\right|>\frac{1}{2}
$$

As we can see, $\left|f(x)-\frac{3}{2}\right|>\frac{1}{2}$ always and hence we can not find $\delta>0$ for $\varepsilon \leq \frac{1}{2}$

Is this a legit proof? Or am I wrong somewhere?

Comment: the negation of the definition is $\exists\varepsilon>0\ \forall\delta>0$ such that $|x-a|<\delta$ but $|f(x)-L|\ge\varepsilon$.

Comment: As is stated above and elsewhere, the idea for continuity is that if you are continuous, every error tolerance on the output ($\epsilon $) has a small enough neighborhood $\delta$ that one can make sure when we evaluate the function in that small neighborhood of $x$ we are no more than $\epsilon$ error away.  So to disprove it, you just need to find one error level that no such delta exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, what you are supposed to prove is that there is some $\varepsilon>0$ such that, for any $\delta>0$, there is some $x\in\Bbb R$ such that $\left|x-1\right|<\delta$ and $\left|f(x)-\frac32\right|\geqslant\varepsilon$. Take $\varepsilon=\frac12$. If $\delta>0$, take $x<1$. Then $f(x)<1$, and therefore $\left|f(x)-\frac32\right|>\frac12=\varepsilon$.